# temperature Sensor error Resistor YSi400

Tags: resistors, sensor, temperature, ltspice, error

[image]I want to simulate the error resistor of a temperature sensor either Pt1000 or YSi400 and I am getting stuck at the point of how should I define this Resistor in LTspice. The value of the error Resistor is like in the flow diagram calculated and question is how can I set an error Resistor that changes value with the change of temperature. I want two different values of the error Resistor one for 40°C and one for 1°C.

If the question of what an Error Resistor can be is that I am trying to simulate the problem when we have a leak contact of the conectors or cables and the temperature will be some grade Celcius more than it really is.

I hope you understand the question and have an asnwer for me.

kind regards

Felix

[image: flow_diagram]gur.com/71OfQ.png

Comment: What´s Rf? I don't see it in the schematic anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you only need a resistor that has two values, one at T1 and the other at T2? Then, if the parameter `T` is stepped, all you need to do is assign this to the value of the resistor:

`{table(T, 1, R1, 40, R2)}`

where `R1` and `R2` are the two values you want. You could do it with an `if()`, but this way it linearly interpolates between the points (avoids discontinuities a bit).

---

(Edit: actually, it's not necesarily to step the value, but the explanation makes a bit more sense because of the two specific values you need, that's all.)

Answer (score 1):

A way to test resistance with a time series simulation is to add a variable resistor with a voltage net substituting in for the resistance:

The circled red net label Res is actually a voltage.

The resistor you want to simulate is in the other red circle, in the resistance value box you put R={*value*}, if you want a time dependent resistance you can add a voltage source and do whatever you want, in this case I have added a PWL source with a ram signal (green circle).

I can either step or ramp the resistance. Keep in mind that the voltage net needs to be a resistance value but it is really a voltage. The V(Res) tells spice that you want to extract just the voltage portion of the net. One can also put equations in the box such as R={V(Res)*2+2} or R={exp(V(Res))}

See [undocumented lt wiki](http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=Undocumented_LTspice) for details

In this way you can test your filter and opamp in a transient simulation.

[image]